# Can I get a list of Google Cloud builds in a Google Cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

So in our yaml files we have this Bash script:

```
gcloud builds list --ongoing
```

However I would need this same list in a Google Cloud Function which is just an `index.js` file with:

```
exports.processPubSubMessage = (event, context) => {
    // ...
}
```

Is this possible? Didn't find an answer by googling around.

Edit: the backstory is I want to prevent this function to publish a message depending on the state of builds by certain triggers.

Comment: You are looking for this, which even has example code for node.js: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library

Comment: wow, how did I not find that... thanks

Comment: @somethingsomething can you post that as an answer? so that it will be helpful for others who are looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the document which has example code for node.js: [cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/)